# Retrieve the Active Accessibility Name of a UI element with plain C

Tags: c, com, ui-automation

**Objective:** Retrieve the Microsoft active accessibility name of the UI element with plain C

My code so far:

```
IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern *legacy = NULL;
BSTR element_aaname = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);
      
  EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CUIAutomation;
  EXTERN_C const IID IID_IUIAutomation;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CUIAutomation,NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,&IID_IUIAutomation,(void**)&pAutomation);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  hr = IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern_get_CurrentName(legacy,&element_aaname);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
 
    }
  IUnknown_Release(legacy);
  }

CoUninitialize();
```

**Problem:** I am not getting any value and I would like to know how to assign `element_aaname="Not found"` to validate if the function works or not. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you use IUIAutomationElement get_CurrentName? Have you checked it works?

Comment: @SimonMourier Tks for your help. As far as I understood the name element is different of the Microsoft Active Accessibility Name. Is that correct?

Comment: They should be the same in general, but your code doesn't show how you get legacy reference. You can use the "inspect" tool from Windows SDK to check all that prior writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the respective documentation I found the way. I have to retrieve and pass the Ui element and this way I can retrieve the LegacyIAccessible.Name:

```
IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
IUIAutomationElement *element = NULL;
BSTR element_aaname = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);
      
  EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CUIAutomation;
  EXTERN_C const IID IID_IUIAutomation;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CUIAutomation,NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,&IID_IUIAutomation,(void**)&pAutomation);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  GetCursorPos(&pt);
  hr = IUIAutomation_ElementFromPoint(pAutomation, pt, &element);
  if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && element != NULL){ 
    hr = IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern_get_CurrentName(element,&element_aaname);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
 
    }
  }
}
```